# Getting error while using SharedPreferences in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am using shared preference like shown below :

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
    var darkModeOn = prefs.getBool('darkMode') ?? true;
    runApp(
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeNotifier>(
        create: (_) => ThemeNotifier(darkModeOn ? darkTheme : lightTheme),
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

But getting error like this while running the application :

```
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12/lib/shared_preferences.dart:11:8: Error: Error when reading '/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_linux-0.0.2+2/lib/shared_preferences_linux.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:shared_preferences_linux/shared_preferences_linux.dart';
       ^
/E:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12/lib/shared_preferences.dart:38:53: Error: Method not found: 'SharedPreferencesLinux'.
          SharedPreferencesStorePlatform.instance = SharedPreferencesLinux();
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'E:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'E:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Although I am doing it on windows platform, I don't know why it tries to get instance of SharedPreferencesLinux().

So can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the version 0.5.7+3.

Comment: @Isaudon It works for now but will have to check it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and i finally found the solution. Just go to C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\shared_preferences_linux-2.0.0 folder and make a lib folder if there is no one already there. Then in that folder just add this file - https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences_linux/lib/shared_preferences_linux.dart